# Excel Column Missing Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet that has a Name Date match in two columns for one list, and the same name date match for two columns in a 2nd list.

One list is longer than the other, how can I find the data that is missing in the matching date/name from the other list?

For instance let's say

```
List 1                       List2
1/2/2012 Tim                 1/2/2012 Tim
2/2/2012 Jill                2/2/2012 Jill
3/2/2012 Bob
```

So basically I need to search list one and find out that List 2 is missing "3/2/2012 Bob" both the dates and names are in their own columns.

How do I do this? Keeping in mind that these lists have no order and that it is possible that someone in list2 might show up in list1 just not on the same row.

Comment: Have you tried something? Something with vlookup? Match? Index? Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If List 1 is in columns `A` and `B`, and List2 is in columns `C` and `D`, then select an area the same size as List 1 (or the size of List 1 minus List2--make sure it has 2 columns) and enter this as an array formula (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:B4,SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH(A2:A4&B2:B4,C2:C3&D2:D3,0)+ROWS(A2:A4),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A2:A4)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A2:A4)))),{1,2}),"")
```

Expand the rows as needed. Also, you'll need to format the first output column as a date.

**EXPLANATION UPDATE**
The Evaluate Formula dialogue is helpful for breaking down complicated formulas. Select the cell with the formula and press <kbd>alt</kbd> then <kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>F</kbd> ("TUF" for tough formulas...).

Start with the `MATCH` function. Since we're looking for a date-name match, concatenate the name and date columns with `&`. `MATCH` will tell us which pairs in List 1 are also in List2 (specifically where--we'll get an array of indices in List2 where the matches were found in List 1). If a match is not found, it will return `#NA`. So for the OP's example `MATCH` will return {1;2;#NA} (the first value in the List 1 array is in position 1 in List2, the second value is in position 2, and the third value was not found in List2).

The second argument in the inner `IFERROR` is an array of the indices of List 1. `ROWS` returns the number of rows in a range, `INDIRECT` returns a safe (meaning it won't be accidentally deleted or moved) reference to rows 1 through the number returned by `ROWS`, and `ROW` returns the row number of each of the rows--so in the OP's example, this is {1;2;3}.

We want the elements from List 1 that were *not* found in List2, so we add the number of rows in List 1 to the non-error `MATCH` results. This will send those values to the end of the array returned by `SMALL`. For the OP's example, the array passed as the first argument to `SMALL` is {4;5;3}.

Now we want to bring the indices of interest to the top using `SMALL`. We use `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A2:A4)))` again as the second argument in `SMALL` to sort the array smallest to largest. For the OP's example, the resulting array is {3;4;5}.

We then pass that array to `INDEX` as the "row_num" argument and {1,2} as the column argument. `INDEX` will then pull both columns from the range that we give as its first argument for each row in the array that resulted from `SMALL`. The values at the end of the array that resulted from `SMALL` are larger than the number of rows in List 1 (since we added `ROWS(A2:A4)` to them), so they will result in `#REF!` errors. These correspond the the elements that returned a match in the `MATCH` function. We wrap this with yet another `IFERROR` to blank out the errors.

Comment: could you explain what your formula does?

Comment: List 1 is Columns A and B, List 2 is Columns D and E.

I need to compare List 1 and List 2 and find out which Date/Name pairs are missing in List 2. 

I know there are 4 missing pairs that are in list 1 but not list 2 I just need to figure out which 4.

Comment: If it's always 4, then you only need to select a 4 row by 2 column area when you enter the formula.

Comment: @LioraHaydont Updated with a rather lengthy explanation.